# Is there a reason why Dave asks HAL to rotate the pod while he's having his secret conversation with Frank?

Tags: plot-explanation, 2001-a-space-odyssey

When Dave takes Frank to the pod to have a secret conversation about HAL making a mistake, they enter it through the door on it's backside but then he asks HAL to rotate it so that the window is facing the inside of the ship where HAL can clearly see them. Now I know that he didn't figure that HAL would be able to read their lips while they talked, but still it seems like a smarter idea to just keep out of HAL's sight. Was the only reason so that the audience can clearly understand that first HAL can hear them until Dave switches the communications off and, of course, so that the plot can progress with HAL learning of their plan to shut him off?

Comment: This was already covered on SciFi - https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/77091/2001-film-lip-reading-scene-why-does-bowman-tell-hal-to-rotate-the-pod